How can i use RViz2 MotionPlanning with default planner_id?
Every time i open rviz2, The planning library is set to pilz but planner_id is still unspecified, and i can not plan because it raises error:
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1730088833.382673498] [rviz2.moveit.ros.move_group_interface]: MoveGroup action client/server ready
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1730088833.384028268] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.move_group.move_action]: MoveGroupMoveAction: Received request
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1730088833.384426430] [rviz2.moveit.ros.move_group_interface]: Planning request accepted
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1730088833.384683025] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.move_group.move_action]: executing..
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1730088833.390435457] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.move_group.move_action]: Planning request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning pipeline.
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1730088833.390545456] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.move_group.capability]: Using planning pipeline 'pilz_industrial_motion_planner'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1730088833.390767550] [move_group]: Calling PlanningRequestAdapter 'ResolveConstraintFrames'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1730088833.390842908] [move_group]: Calling PlanningRequestAdapter 'ValidateWorkspaceBounds'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1730088833.390867143] [move_group]: Calling PlanningRequestAdapter 'CheckStartStateBounds'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1730088833.390938380] [move_group]: Calling PlanningRequestAdapter 'CheckStartStateCollision'
[move_group-4] [ERROR] [1730088833.391161661] [move_group.moveit.moveit.planners.pilz.command_planner]: Cannot service planning request because planner ID '' does not exist.
[move_group-4] [ERROR] [1730088833.391199864] [move_group.moveit.moveit.planners.pilz.command_planner]: No ContextLoader for planner_id '' found. Planning not possible.
[move_group-4] [ERROR] [1730088833.391206638] [move_group]: Failed to create PlanningContext for planner 'Pilz Industrial Motion Planner'. Aborting planning pipeline.
[move_group-4] [ERROR] [1730088833.391227451] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.move_group.move_action]: Generating a plan with planning pipeline failed.
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1730088833.391277597] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.move_group.move_action]: FAILURE
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1730088833.391894639] [rviz2.moveit.ros.move_group_interface]: Planning request aborted
[rviz2-2] [ERROR] [1730088833.392225335] [rviz2.moveit.ros.move_group_interface]: MoveGroupInterface::plan() failed or timeout reached

Although i can set it manually, but every time i restart rviz2 i need to do it, is there any config where i can set a default option for it?
The rviz panel: https://ibb.co/8P7Sc1m
